# JFrame center components

Tags: java, swing, jframe, centering, gridbaglayout

I was wondering how to center my components, I found the gridBagLayout but I couldn't find a way to have it bigger than it is : my buttons are too small.

Part of my code :

```
private void addMainButtons() {
        JPanel container = new JPanel() {
            private static final long serialVersionUID = -424395301619105440L;

            @Override
            protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
                super.paintComponent(g);
                Dimension dim = this.getSize();
                DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
                Date date = new Date();
                g.setFont(new Font("TimesRoman", Font.PLAIN, 20));
                g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
                String s = format.format(date);
                g.drawString(s, (int) ((dim.getWidth() - s.length() - 80) / 2), 20);
            }
        };
        container.setBackground(new Color(109, 69, 60));

        JButton productsButton = new JButton("Produits");
        productsButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                cl.show(frame, pages[1]);
            }
        });
        productsButton.setAlignmentY(Component.CENTER_ALIGNMENT);
        productsButton.setAlignmentX(Component.CENTER_ALIGNMENT);

        // Creating grid
        container.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400, 600));
        container.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

        GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = 0;
        gbc.gridwidth = 2;
        container.add(productsButton, gbc);

        gbc.gridy = 1;
        gbc.gridwidth = 1;
        container.add(new JButton("Entrée"), gbc);

        gbc.gridx = 1;
        container.add(new JButton("Sortie"), gbc);

        mainPage.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        mainPage.add(container, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        // End of main page
    }
```

GridBagLayout is really difficult to use, is there another way to center components ? I could use NestedLayouts but I don't know how.

Comment: You can effect the size of the components in a `GridBagLayout` using `ipadx` and `ipady`.  You might also need to use `fill` to make components fill the available space of their cell

Comment: Consider providing a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem. This is not a code dump, but an example of what you are doing which highlights the problem you are having. This will result in less confusion and better responses.  You might also want to explain you expectations better, saying your buttons "are to small" really doesn't help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `weightx` and/or `weighty` to effect the amount of space the components will occupy, for example, if I do

```
GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
gbc.gridx = 0;
gbc.gridy = 0;
gbc.gridwidth = 2;

gbc.weightx = 1;
gbc.weighty = 1;

container.add(productsButton, gbc);

gbc.gridy = 1;
gbc.gridwidth = 1;
container.add(new JButton("Entrée"), gbc);

gbc.gridx = 1;
container.add(new JButton("Sortie"), gbc);
```

I can generate this...

[image: Big Buttons]

You could use two containers, one holding a `JLabel` which shows the date and one which contains the buttons, but I doubt that's what you're really after.

You can use `ipadx` and `ipady` which adds the amount to the components preferred size

```
GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
gbc.gridx = 0;
gbc.gridy = 0;
gbc.gridwidth = 2;

gbc.ipadx = 40;
gbc.ipady = 40;

container.add(productsButton, gbc);

gbc.gridy = 1;
gbc.gridwidth = 1;
container.add(new JButton("Entrée"), gbc);

gbc.gridx = 1;
container.add(new JButton("Sortie"), gbc);
```

[image: Not so big buttons]

which, when included with your existing constraints, allows you to "grow" the buttons a bit.

Answer (score 0):

Try below code for increasing size of button while adding every components to gridbagconstraints. Change the value of weightx/weighty as you want.

```
gbc.weightx = 1.0;
gbc.weighty = 1.0;
```

To give more spaces between components, use below code while adding every components to gridbagconstraints.

```
gbc.insets = new Insets(2, 2, 2, 2);
```

According to my knowledge, you used correct way to center components. It can also be done by other layout but it may be little bit difficult.